# Login LOL from command line

Tags: league-of-legends

I have multiple accounts with its unique passwords but I do not want to type it again if I want to switch to another account. So, I want to write a batch file so that I can login by clicking it. However, I do not know the options of launcher.exe. Is there any options that I can use to login?

Comment: That's such a massive security risk.

Comment: @Frank if someone else has access to OP's local machine, there are bigger things at stake than LOL account credentials

Comment: I think launching it that way actually violates ToS

Comment: @GodEmperorDune Yeah, but keeping it in a freaking batch file?  Might as well just put it in a file called password.txt.

Comment: @Frank I login linux server using putty in this way, why it would a risk for LOL?

Comment: @TerrenceLiao its the same risk for your putty login too. I would recommend using a key based authentication for ssh instead of leaving a plaintext password lying around. AFAIK, LOL does not have a key based authentication scheme as an alternative to username/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there's nothing available for what you're asking. The biggest reason is that the client is built to be launched by the patcher, not by users (allowing the game to start without going through the patcher would risk people playing with out-of-date software, or allow mods to go unchecked). Since the patcher has no way to use your credentials (and indeed *shouldn't* hold them), there'd be little reason to include that as something the for the game client to receive from it.

Hypothetically there could be console commands, but unfortunately, until they publish such commands (which they probably wouldn't), the only way to actually find out what console commands are available would be to reverse engineer the client, which is both difficult and in breach of their ToS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in pursuing this, I just finished an AHK script that could probably do the trick with some modification. Check it out here: https://github.com/telmer6/lolpass

Comment: thanks for contributing ideas! AHK script is new to me, so I might need to take a look at it.

Comment: Actually, I just modified the script to allow multiple users via .ini files. You can just make shortcuts to run the script with the account you want.

Comment: NECRO! @TerrenceLiao I've reworked this for reliability and user friendliness if you are still interested: https://github.com/telmer6/LoLPass/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta

Comment: nice one! This is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot after such a long time. This is performing pretty well!

Comment: Glad it's of use!